# swagger-php having different documentations from the same code

Tags: php, swagger, slim, swagger-php

We are using slim framework and swagger-php to dynamically generate the swagger documentation. 
We now have some special methods in the API that should not be publicly documentated. (/doc now)
Is there any way I can have a second documentation url (/doc2) where I can get the secret methods and params documentated? (without having to make the documentation by hand, just using the annotations in the php code). Thanks.

Comment: Are the private interfaces in seperate files or mixed with public ones?

Comment: mostly are hidden parameters to existing methods, so in the same file. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I am not sure about PHP but swagger maven plugin (java) you can specify which files contain the rest interfaces. If this exists in php too, you could move private interfaces to separate files and then call swagger with different configuration. Almost like splitting the project. Or.. modify the swagger export with a post processing script somehow. This is the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the latest version of swagger-php you can indicate a list of files and/or directories to exclude from scanning when building the documentation.

See the scan function's [docblock](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/src/functions.php#L20) on github for details.

A solution to your problem is to separate the public and private methods into different files. Then create two documentation generation methods/functions each excluding the other's files.

***Example:***

```
$privateOptions = array(
    'exclude' => array('app/api/public')
);
$privateDoc = Swagger\scan("app/", $privateOptions);
...
$publicOptions = array(
    'exclude' => array('app/api/private')
);
$publicDoc = Swagger\scan("app/", $publicOptions);
```

**Note:** This example is indicative and not tested, you can also exclude filenames.