# Swagger php - filtering public/private APIs without splitting up code

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-php

I am considering using Zircote Swagger PHP to document an API. I am not fully familiar with it yet, since I've been trying to answer this question before committing to using it.

I want two different sets of documentation. One doc page will include all of our APIs, and the other will include only those APIs that should be documented publicly.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225937/swagger-php-having-different-documentations-from-the-same-code) which more or less gives me the results  I am looking for. However, the solution they suggest requires that I refactor my existing code significantly as the implementation of our public and private APIs are not yet split up in the way that answer suggests.

Is there a way to tag individual APIs in annotations, and filter on those tags when I generate documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented yet, but I believe a PR would be welcomed.

For the time being you can post-process generated docs, e.g. piping it thru a single-liner:

```
swagger /path/to/project | php -r '$s = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://stdin"),true);array_walk($s["paths"],function(&$p){$p=array_filter($p,function($m){return count(array_intersect(["tag1","tag2"],$m["tags"]))==0;});});file_put_contents("php://stdout",json_encode($s,192));' > public.json
```

Formatting for readability:

```
$s = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://stdin"), true);
array_walk(
    $s["paths"],
    function (&$path) {
        $path = array_filter(
            $path,
            function ($method) {
                return count(array_intersect(["tag1", "tag2"], $method["tags"])) == 0;
            }
        );
    }
);
file_put_contents("php://stdout", json_encode($s, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

Where `tag1` and `tag2` are tags to exclude.